# (Angular) Karma Jasmine test is showing failure for a working feature

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, karma-jasmine, angular-test

I'm trying to write a unit test for a directive that is supposed to open a popup when it's clicked.

The directive works perfectly when i test it manually, however, the unit test shows failure which I don't understand.

Test:

```
@Component({
  template: '<button class="btn" PopupTarget target="my_modal">open modal</button>' +
    '<popup popupId="my_modal">hello</popup>'
})
export class TesterComponent {
}


describe('PopupTargetDirective', () => {

  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TesterComponent>
  let directive: PopupTargetDirective;
  let button: HTMLButtonElement;
  let popup: DebugElement

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [PopupTargetDirective, TesterComponent, PopupComponent]
    })
      .compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TesterComponent);
    button = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector(".btn")
    directive = new PopupTargetDirective(new ElementRef<any>(button));
    popup = fixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(PopupComponent)).nativeElement
  });

  it('should create an instance', () => {

    expect(directive).toBeTruthy();
  })

  it('should show popup when clicked', () => {

    let dialog: HTMLDialogElement | null = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector("dialog")
    console.log(button)

    expect(dialog?.open).toBeFalse()
    button.click()
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      expect(dialog?.open).toBeTrue()
    })


  })

});
```

Directive:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[PopupTarget]'
})
export class PopupTargetDirective {

  @Input() target : string = '';

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
    el.nativeElement.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
      let targetPopup: HTMLDialogElement | null = document.getElementById(this.target) as HTMLDialogElement;
      targetPopup?.showModal()
    })
  }
}
```

popup HTML:

```
<dialog #dialog id="{{popupId}}" class="modal tw-rounded-md"
        (close)="this.onClose.emit()"
        (cancel)="cancel($event)"
>

  <form method="dialog" class="modal-box">

    <div class="tw-flex tw-flex-col tw-justify-center">
      <button #closeButton class="tw-self-end" *ngIf="showCloseButton">✕</button>
      <ng-content class="tw-self-auto"></ng-content>
    </div>

  </form>
</dialog>
```

Popup ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'popup',
  templateUrl: './popup.component.html'
})
export class PopupComponent {

  @Input() showCloseButton: boolean = false;
  @Input({required: true}) popupId: string | undefined;
  @Output() onClose: EventEmitter<void> = new EventEmitter()
  @ViewChild("dialog") dialog: ElementRef<HTMLDialogElement> | undefined
  @ViewChild("closeButton") closeButton: ElementRef<HTMLButtonElement> | undefined

  cancel(event: Event) {
    if (!this.showCloseButton) event.preventDefault()
    else
      this.onClose.emit()
  }
}
```

Is there something wrong with my test code? As I mentioned it works perfectly fine when I test it manually so this is probably the case.

Comment: Could you please add the output of your test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In tests you need to take care of change detection on your own by calling `fixture.detectChanges()`. In your test, there is no change detection done, so the component is not initialized, nor updated after the click.

Please call `fixture.detectChanges()` after the `TestBed.createComponent` line (to initialize the component) and after `button.click()` (to update the view after the click). After `button.click()`, query the dialog again, now it should be found.

To debug tests it is often helpful to run the test in non-headless browser mode, so that you can see which components are rendered at all. In karma you can configure this in your `karma.conf.js` file.